# Аналог пинг-понга в многопоточности

Tags: java, многопоточность

Не могу понять, почему в данном примере не получается работать с 2 потоками

```
public class Start {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Start start = new Start();
        start.init();

    }

    private void init() {
        Game game = new Game();
        MyThread myThread1 = new MyThread(game, "Ping");
        MyThread myThread2 = new MyThread(game, "Pong");
        myThread1.start();
        myThread2.start();
    }

    private class MyThread extends Thread {
        Game game;

        public MyThread(Game game, String name) {
            setName(name);
            this.game = game;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (game.isGameNotOver()) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                game.kick(getName());
            }
        }
    }

    private class Game {

         int counter = 0;

        public synchronized void kick(String name) {
            System.out.println(name + "  " + counter);
            counter++;
        }

        public boolean isGameNotOver() {
            return counter < 10;
        }
    }
}
```

А именно, если Sleep стоит <=100, то возможны ситуации что 1 поток сделает всю работы. Если поставить 500, то проблема перестанет наблюдаться.

Пытался сделать по аналогии с этой [задачей](https://geekbrains.ru/posts/multithread_pingpong) Но только убрал синглтон и проверку по имени потока. Явно ведь, проверка имени это какая-то.... не обычность.

Comment: вы просто синхронизировали метод `kick`, что означает, что одновременно внутри метода может быть только один поток. Всё, больше никаких гарантий у вас нет. Потому нет ничего удивительного, что есть вероятность .что один поток сделает всю работу. Мало того, при маленьком значенни в thread.sleep(...), первый поток может сделать всю работу просто потому, что второй поток не успел ещё стартануть к тому моменту - запуск потока таки дорогая операция.

Comment: Я бы на вашем месте wait-notify использовал.

Comment: @tym32167, отлично, допустим он стартанет за следующие 200 мс, тогда почему дальше не идет конкуренция между потоками? Типо 1 вошел в `synchronized` метод, а когда вышел, тут уже второй заходит сразу.

Comment: @Miron вполне-вполне. Но, так ли решаются задачи на проде? Не вдаваясь в ExecutorService и пулы.

Comment: я не спец в java, потому дальнейшее - чисто мое предположение. Доупстим я планировщик задач и отвечаю за переклчение потоков. И я вижу, что первый поток хочет подождать 100мс, а потом вызвать синхронизированную функцию, которую ждет втрой поток. Допустим, я знаю, что, чтобы стопануть первый поток и разбудить второй поток и вызвать метод вторым потоком, мне надо 110мс. Таким образом, с точки зрения быстродействия, мне выгодней продолжить работу с первым потоком, чем стопануть первый поток и разбудить второй, так как само по себе переключение между состояниями потоков - тоже дорогая операция.

Comment: так как вы написали в вопросе - так точно вопросы не решаются на проде. Вы в вашем коде ориентируетесь на предположения и тайминги, что не приемлемо с точки зрения синхронизации потоков.

Comment: @tym32167, да, `sleep` здесь чтобы понять границу в какой момент программа начинает работать так, как я ожидаю. На 500 мс она работает как надо. В примере из GeekBrains она работает еще за счет проверки имени. Я до этого давно, на собеседовании тоже реализовывал через проверку имени потока, но, мне кажется это лишнее и можно как-то без этого, только используя модификаторы

Answer (score 1):

DL: первый раз работаю с синхронизацией в java, так что критика приветствуется.

Я немного прокачал класс Game

```
private class Game {
    volatile int counter = 0;
    volatile boolean isPing = true;

    public synchronized void waitFor(boolean isPing) {
        while (isPing() != isPing && isGameNotOver()) {
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public synchronized void kick(boolean isPing) {
        System.out.println((isPing ? "Ping": "Pong") + "  " + counter);
        counter++;
        this.isPing = !isPing;
        this.notifyAll();
    }

    public boolean isPing() {
        return isPing;
    }

    public boolean isGameNotOver() {
        return counter < 100;
    }
}
```

С такой прокачкой, мы видим, что поток будет ждать нужного состояния игры, чтобы сделать ход.

```
private class MyThread extends Thread {
    Game game;

    private boolean isPing() {
        return "Ping".equals(getName());
    }

    public MyThread(Game game, String name) {
        setName(name);
        this.game = game;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (game.isGameNotOver()) {
            game.waitFor(isPing());
            if (game.isGameNotOver())
                game.kick(isPing());
        }
    }
}
```

Как вы видите, тут мы не завсим от таймингов, а условие изменения состояния игры детерминировано. При таких условиях мы даже можем добавить игроков и все равно увидим, что Ping и Pong будут корректно чередоваться

```
private void init() {
    Game game = new Game();
    MyThread myThread1 = new MyThread(game, "Ping");
    MyThread myThread2 = new MyThread(game, "Pong");
    MyThread myThread3 = new MyThread(game, "Ping");
    MyThread myThread4 = new MyThread(game, "Pong");

    myThread1.start();
    myThread2.start();
    myThread3.start();
    myThread4.start();
}
```

Вывод

```
Ping  0
Pong  1
...
Ping  96
Pong  97
Ping  98
Pong  99
```

Comment: Вы, получается добавили туже проверку как в том, примере из GeekBrains. Только там была проверка по имени, а тут проверка по boolean. В итоге, тоже самое только через другую переменную.

Comment: не совсем. Я ещё добавил ожидание для хода. То есть если последний ход был Ping, то следующий может быть только Pong. То есть в моем варианте гарантируется, что ping и pong будут чередоваться. В вашем варианте или  в той статье такой гарантии нет.

Answer (score 0):

Минимальный пинг понг

```
public class PingPong {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final var numberOfPlays = 20;
        new Thread(() -> play("ping", numberOfPlays)).start();
        new Thread(() -> play("pong", numberOfPlays)).start();
    }

    private static synchronized void play(String name, int numberOfPlays) {
        while (true) {
            System.out.println(name);
            try {
                PingPong.class.notify();
                if (--numberOfPlays == 0) {
                    break;
                } else {
                    PingPong.class.wait();
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```